# Recall method in cypress until a button is no longer visible

Tags: typescript, automation, cypress

How can I write the method below from cypress so that the "show more upcoming" button is only pressed while it is visible. At this time the method causes the button to be pressed even after it is no longer visible and automatically generates an error. I've tried to use a kind of recursive function.

I've also tried that intercept to always load the appointment list, but I'm not sure it's necessarily useful.

I hope I've provided all the details, thank you.

```
  checkVisibilityUpcoming(): void {
        cy.get(".mat-flat-button.mat-primary").then($button => {
            if($button.is(':visible')) {
                cy.intercept('https://apilink').as('upcoming')
                cy.contains('Show more upcoming').click();
                cy.wait('@upcoming')
                this.checkVisibilityUpcoming()
            }
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a `.then()` around the 2nd, 3rd, ... calls.

Everything else is on the Cypress command queue, so adding the recursive call to the queue should give you the right sequence of events.

```js
cy.intercept('https://apilink').as('upcoming')

checkVisibilityUpcoming(): void {
  cy.get(".mat-flat-button.mat-primary").then($button => {
    if($button.is(':visible')) {
      cy.contains('Show more upcoming').click();
      cy.wait('@upcoming')
        .then(() => this.checkVisibilityUpcoming())
    }
  })
}
```

Depending on how long it takes the app re-render after receiving the api call, you may need to add a wait of 100ms or so between calls

```js
cy.intercept('https://apilink').as('upcoming')

checkVisibilityUpcoming(): void {
  cy.get(".mat-flat-button.mat-primary").then($button => {
    if($button.is(':visible')) {
      cy.contains('Show more upcoming').click();
      cy.wait('@upcoming')
      cy.wait(100)          // for processing after the api completes
        .then(() => this.checkVisibilityUpcoming())
    }
  })
}
```

---

**Testing button existence**

Piecing together clues from the comments,

1. `cy.get(".mat-flat-button.mat-primary").then($button =>` and `cy.contains('Show more upcoming')` refer to the same button. `.mat-flat-button.mat-primary` is not a very strong selector, other button may have these classes and incorrectly pass your  `.is(':visible')` check.
2. ***Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find content: 'Show more upcoming' but never did*** implies that the button isn't just invisible, but it no longer exists after a certain number of iterations.

To test existence instead of visibility, you will need a parent element of the button. You could use `<body>` if the button selector is unique on the page.

Also use the text of the button to make sure you target the one-and-only button each time, e.g `'button:contains("Show more upcoming")'`.

See if this variation is any better.

```js
const buttonSelector = 'button:contains("Show more upcoming")';

checkVisibilityUpcoming(attempts = 0): void {

  // always good to guard against infinite recursion 
  if (attempts > 10) {     // adjust the limit appropriately
    throw 'Too many attempts'
  }

  cy.get('body').then($body => {

    const buttonExists = $body.find(buttonSelector).length === 1;
    if (buttonExists) {
      cy.get(buttonSelector).click();
      cy.wait('@upcoming')
      cy.wait(100)          // for processing after the api completes
        .then(() => this.checkVisibilityUpcoming(++attempts))
    }
  })
}

// Call by initially finding the button
cy.get(buttonSelector).then(() => {
  // button exists at start now call the clicker
  checkVisibilityUpcoming();
})
```

If you still have problems, add some `console.log()` statements to see what is there on each recursion.

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried both versions posted by you looking for the button and when it no longer exists, then the error appears and the test crashes. Do you have other similar variants? Thanks

Comment: What's the error? Is the button removed instead of becoming invisible?

Comment: This is the error: "Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find content: 'Show more upcoming' but never did."

Comment: Sorry about previous incongruous question, my keyboard is playing up. What I meant to ask was - Is `cy.contains('Show more upcoming')` the same button as you test here `$button.is(':visible')` or a different one?

Comment: It is the same button

Comment: Ok, ta. I'll try it out and see if I can get a fix.

Comment: I think the problem may be that there are other buttons matching `.mat-flat-button.mat-primary`. That lets the code get passed `cy.get(".mat-flat-button.mat-primary")` on recursive calls. Note the error `Timed out retrying after 4000ms...` implies the button doesn't exist (rather than just being invisible).